# ¿Cuál sería la equivalencia de dos selectores de JQuery en Javascript ES6?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quisiera hacer lo siguiente en Javascript nativo

```
$(".divPadre div").on("click", "button.claseDos", function(){
    var id_button = $(this).attr("id_button");
    // petición ajax
})
```

Cabe destacar que el button se agrega de manera dinamica después de un evento javascript.

Con dos QuerySelector no lo conseguí...

Edit:

```
<div class="divPadre">
</div>
```

Después el `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success claseDos">OK</button>` se agrega con un evento click.

Comment: ¿Podrías dar un poco mas de contexto así como añadir tu HTML?

Comment: Editado! @BetaM

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres acceder al botón dentro del `div`, puedes utilizar `querySelector` de la siguiente manera:

```
const button = document.querySelector("div.divPadre button.claseDos");
```

Posteriormente, añades el evento click al botón con `addEventListener` para que finalmente obtengas el atributo `id_button` con `getAttribute`:

```
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    const buttonId = this.getAttribute('id_button');
    alert(buttonId);
});
```

Aquí te dejo el [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xmefdcu4/) por si quieres intentarlo.

Comment: Ok, funciona porque el button está cargado directamente en el html, en mi caso se carga después de un event onclick con javascript...

Comment: Entonces quieres que el botón se agregué dinámicamente junto con el evento?

Comment: Tu pregunta radica en los selectores y su equivalente. En tu código no muestras nada sobre la manera en la que creas un botón para mostrarte el equivalente.